# ERROR ReferenceError: config is not defined Angular 7

Tags: angular, webpack

I have tried all the solutions on stack with similar question:

[image]

The error occur at this point:

```
 return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
```

webpack.config.js

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // global app config object
            config: JSON.stringify({
                apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
            })
        })
```

typings.d.ts

```
declare var config: any;
```

authentication.service.ts

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    debugger;
    return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
        .pipe(map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            }

            return user;
        }));
}
```

Comment: What is `config`? Why is not defined? Where do you declare, or import it?

Comment: show the login function of authentication.service.ts

Comment: @FranklinPious I have done that

Answer (score 1):

There's no link between the `config` prop that you use on webpack's config and between the one you use in the http client.

You can store the config as an external constant to the object that you pass to webpack. Something like this:

```
    export const config = JSON.stringify({
        apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
    })

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        config, // this is same as `config: config,`
    })
```

and then in your service you'll do

```
import { config } from 'path/to/webpack/config/file';

... your stuff here ...

return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to declare your "apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'" inside "environment.ts" file like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
};
```

File is located under your project: "src/environments/environment.ts". There is a prod version too.

Access the value in your code like this:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

Then in your class (app.component.ts):

```
  constructor() {
    console.log('config.apiUrl', environment.apiUrl);
  }
```